# WPF - Removing Hover State when using keyboard inside a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to remove the hover state that a user might have on a `ComboBoxItem` when this user is using the keyboard arrows to navigate through the items. But, when the user moves his mouse over an item, the hover state / selection state goes to this item.

Right now, with a stock WPF `ComboBox`, I found out that there is three states with different combinaisons: focused, hover, selected. For example, in the following screenshot, the `item3` is the one that was selected, `item5` has the mouse hover state and the `item7` is the one with the keyboard focus.

[image]

I want the behaviour of my ComboBox to be like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <body>
      <select>
        <option value="Item1">Item #1</option>
        <option value="Item2">Item #2</option>
        <option value="Item3">Item #3</option>
        <option value="Item4">Item #4</option>
     </select>
   </body>
 </html>
```

- When I enter the drowndown, the "selected" (blue in this case) value is already selected.
- If I mouse over an item, this item becomes the one that is "selected".
- From there, if I use the arrows on my keyboard, the "selected" item is changed and there is no items in the hovered state until I move my mouse again.

I tried using `VisualStates` and `Trigger` on the Selected and MouseOver states, but it didn't seemed to be working. I also checked and it could be done with `EventSetters` but I don't know on which `Event` to attach the handler to detect the mouse mouvement on top of a `ComboBoxItem`.

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: In your HTML example, hovering doesn't actually select the element, because the value inside the combo box itself is not updated.

Comment: You're right. The value is not selected but it is shown as the one that will by selected if I click on it or pressed enter. This would be the behaviour I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this with a simple EventSetter.

```
<EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="ComboBoxItemStyle_OnMouseMove" />
```

This event setter is applied directly to the style of my `ComboBoxItem`. Here is the code of this event handler:

```
private void ComboBoxItemStyle_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hoveredItem = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    hoveredItem?.Focus();
}
```

My `ComboBoxItem` also has the property `OverrideDefaultStyle` to `True` and therefore I can set the way the ComboBoxItems are shown when Hovered, Focused and Selected. I decided to go with VisualStates on the Template of an item in order to do this.

When an item is in the `Focused` state, I set the `Background` to the color I wanted and same thing with the `Foreground`. I also did the same with the `Selected` state. Since, the `MouseMove` event sets the the current hovered item to the one focused, the states kicked in and the styles were set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is your goal, but give it  a try to see if it is what you want:

```
<ComboBox Height="50" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsEditable="False">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsFocused, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Items 1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Items 2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Items 3" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Items 4" />
    </ComboBox>
```

You could have the Combobox bound for ItemsSource, it does not matter when the ComboboxItems come from.

Comment: This helps in a way. But by binding to the selected element, if I hovered, this element would be selected and if I clicked out of the ComboBox, this one would be the one selected even though I didn't select any of them.

Comment: So you are actually looking for the `IsHighlighted` property of  the ComboBoxItem. That should be set to True when you are using the keyboard. The problem is that you cannot do that, if you are targeting a framework > 3.0 (see [url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem.ishighlighted(v=vs.110).aspx) What you can do is make a custom Highlight mechanism, other than the one that the Combobox offers. I can post a solution for this suggestion if you want.

Comment: I wouldn't say no to an answer with the `IsHighlighted` property. I found something also, but maybe yours is better!